# .. plot directive in restructured text

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I was looking at [this site](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html).  Specifically, the [source](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/_sources/users/geography.txt).  It appears to create a plot (complete with source code!) is extremely easy:

```
.. plot: somefile.py
```

But, when I try it, sphinx yells at me.  `"ERROR: Unknown directive type "plot".`  So the question is how do I teach sphinx about the `plot` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` includes a Sphinx directive for a `plot` directive; see their [sample doc for Sphinx](http://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/extensions.html) and the [documenting `matplotlib` chapter](http://matplotlib.org/devel/documenting_mpl.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to activate the plot extension for sphinx (see [this explanation](http://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/extensions.html)). I have not tried it but it may be possible that this suffices:

```
extensions = ['matplotlib.sphinxext.plot_directive']
```

Add this to your `conf.py` to activate `.. plot::`.

**Note**: Sphinx directives start with **two** colons:

```
.. plot::

    ...
```